# OS X Sidecar & Blender?

Tags: sculpting

Will Blender work in sidecar? The idea of Sculpting in Blender with an iPad Pro and Apple Pencil sounds Amazing!

Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

I tested - grease pencil in blender 2.8 currently supports Sidecar with pressure sensitivity. It is a bit quirky at times - but it definitely works!